# Awk comparison and adding a new column with Null values

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have this input with null values in it in a tab separated csv file.I wanna check if a value is e.g., >= 800 or not and add the result to a new column.

input

```
a
623

616
803
```

output

```
a     b
623   no
      no
616   no
803   yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v minval=800 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  FNR==1{ print $0, "b"; next } # print header
  { print $0, ($1 >= minval ? "yes" : "no") }
' file
```

Output:

```
a       b
623     no
        no
616     no
803     yes
```

You don't need an explicit check if the first column is empty. If you compare a string to a number, the number is converted
to a string. And the empty string always comes before any non-empty string when compared lexicographically, thus it is never greater or equal to a non-empty string.